# Visualize personality type in 2d

Tags: 3d, visualization

I have a data file with results from a simple personality test, where a total of 84 points are distributed among three colors, red, green and blue. A sample score could be red=17, blue=39 and green=28.

I want to plot each persons result as a dot in a chart, but I want to avoid using a 3d coordinate system. How could I do this? Notice that the values for each of the colors would never be negative.

Does it exist some kind of triangular coordinate system? Is there already a solution to my problem in the subject of mathematics?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_plot

Comment: Wow, thanks! This looks really good!

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. If you add it as an answer, I will mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ternary plot was the answer I was looking for. Thanks Rahul!
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_plot